# How to encourage voting the right way for questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

In the context of the new badge for voting on questions, what will encourage voting up questions that meet the sites' criteria for good questions, as opposed to the visible tendency for herds of muppets to vote up more or less silly questions?

Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996496/eclipse-ftp-team-plugin). There's no herd here, and it isn't silly, but it seemed to me that the original version had too much opinion per unit query to be a good question according to the criteria. The original had multiple upvotes before I got there. Questions that start with a paragraph of opinion are not, I think, what is desired.

I decided to try an experiment and I decapitated the ranting first paragraph to see what would happen to me. No one has rolled me back yet.

Comment: Doesn't this question start with a sentence of opinion?  I think it's good to give context for some questions, and the problem is going beyond that into ranting or letting off steam (as OPs are probably often frustrated by the time they ask).

Comment: I would vote down my own question on SO. Discussion is explicitly outside the criteria there. Here, on the other hand, there's a tag for it.